# Jquery Append & @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am pulling some data from a database so when you select the person's name from the dropdown list the text field "Login" in the form should auto complete with his details.

At the moment it keeps empty.

I am sure there is some issue when trying to append the javascript data at the @HtmlEditorFor.

Can you please have a look if i am doing something wrong ?

Thank you for your time in advance.

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend><div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLogin)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserLogin, new {id ="LoginId" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLogin)
        </div>
}
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $('#UserID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserForm")',
                data: { ID: $('#UserID').val() },
            success: function (results) {
                var options = $('#LoginId');
                options.empty();         
                $.each(results, function () {
                    options.append($().val(this.ID).text(this.Value));
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetUserForm(string ID)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in StaffDB.StaffData
                       where s.Forename1 + ' ' + s.Surname == ID
                       select new { Value = s.Login, ID = s.ID};


            return Json(data);
        }
```

Comment: hwo does the editor template looks like ?

Comment: What is default behavior of `$()` ? If `options` is a dropdown use `$('<option/>')`

Comment: is the @Html.EditorFor textbox

Comment: Where is the **'#UserID'** coming from in your javascript? You have defined the @Html.EditorFor **id ="LoginId"**

Comment: html.EditorFor() dont take htmlAttributes as parameter, go for Html.textBoxFor()

Comment: See my answer, it will surely help you out @Wizeman1986

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserLogin, new {id ="LoginId" })
```

as

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty,ViewData)
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty,htmlAttributes Object)
```

Or in jQuery selector pass

```
$('#UserLogin')
```

for Editor Selection as it auto generates ID of model property name